# Can't connect to remote Sybase server running in Win XP

Tags: networking, windows-xp, remote-desktop, port

My local application wants to connect to remote `Sybase ASE-16` server  hosted in `XP` machine. It's up and running and I can connect locally but not from another machine in the same domain. I can ping the box successfully, connect to `Tomcat` hosted/listening at `#8080` in the same server(XP)from my machine but not `Sybase` at `#2638`. I had to open port for Tomcat to bypass firewall. But for some reason, `Sybase` still not working with the same procedure.

`Netstat` shows `#2638` listening from local machine, but when I use `Port Query` to remote scan the port from my box, it says `not listening`. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying it is hosted on XP - I would suggest checking Windows Firewall to make sure its listed as a trusted program.  I had this exact problemm running a Minecraft server - all the ports were properly forwarded, but nothing could connect.  It turns out Windows Firewall would not allow connections to it over public connections.  Since Windows Firewall discriminates between different applications, this could explain why Tomcat is reachable but not Sybase.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes it's the firewall causing the issue. I did try adding an exception on the port for Sybase on XP, then running the Port Qry.exe gives me status of `not listening`, if I remove port exception, it says 'Filtered' while running Sybase server all the time. if I comepletely disable FW then it works.